# EIGRP Adjacency Table

Tags: cisco, routing, eigrp

From *Cisco IP Routing* by Alex Zinin

[image: Figure from Alex Zinin’s Book - Cisco IP Routing]
According to this figure Adjacency Table gets messages from DUAL module also.As far as I know, Adjacency Table is populated only because of Hello packets exchanged between different neighbors. 
What is the relationship between Adjacency Table and DUAL module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dual is the algorithm that is used by eigrp to prevent routing loops in the eigrp AS it would have to track changes in the network including neighbor adjacencies.  If a neighbor adjacency fails or a new adjacency occurs this would be relevant to the adjacency table so I could see it would have to be involved at some level with the adjacency table.  Notice when a new adjacency occurs in an eigrp environment you will see the dual-5-nbrchange message followed by a change of some kind in neighbor adjacency.